# How to make the shutter top panel icon to be permanent?

Tags: gnome-panel, panel-applets

I'm running ubuntu 13.10.Whenever i open the shutter application,a shutter icon was displayed on the unity top-panel.But it remains for sometime.

But my question is how to make this icon to be displayed **permanently** on the top-panel after i rebooted my pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the shutter icon in your tray every time you login, you have to add it to your startup applications.

Since you probably don't want to see its window every time you login, add `--min_at_startup` to the call.

Start the program 'Startup Applications', click 'Add', enter a name and description of your choice in the dialog. Then, as command, enter:

```
/usr/bin/shutter --min_at_startup
```

and click the dialog's 'Add' button. Once you logout and in again, the shutter icon should be in your tray.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. However `shutter --min_at_startup` will have the same effect.